# NuGet: How can I set "visible" of content to false with Install.ps1 file?

Tags: powershell, nuget

I know this sets CopyToOutputDirectory to Always
$project.ProjectItems.Item("test.exe").Properties.Item("CopyToOutputDirectory").Value = 1

But when I try to set Visible in the same way it won't work
$project.ProjectItems.Item("test.exe").Properties.Item("Visible").Value = 1 or "false" or $false

Answer (score 0):

test.exe does not have a property item `Visible` so you cannot set the value

You will get an error if you do this

```
$project.ProjectItems.Item("Program.cs").Properties.Item("Visible")
```

This will work because `CopyToOutputDirectory` is an actual property

```
$project.ProjectItems.Item("test.exe").Properties.Item("CopyToOutputDirectory")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection` as an alternative, but making changes in this way would require the project to be reloaded after the package is installed.

```
$buildProject = [Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection]::GlobalProjectCollection.GetLoadedProjects($project.FullName)
$buildProject.Xml.AllChildren|?{$_.Include -eq "test.exe"} | % { 
    if ($_.HasMetadata -and ($visible=$_.Metadata|?{$_.Name -eq "Visible"}))
    {
        $visible.Value = $false
    }
    else
    {
        $_.AddMetadata("Visible",$false)
    }
}
$buildProject.Save()
```

However, it appears to prevent the file from being uninstalled, and I'm not sure `Uninstall.ps1` is called at the appropriate time for visibility to be restored so that NuGet can handle deletion.